# How to split 2d array (matrix) based on some splitting value?

Tags: python, r, algorithm, matrix, split

Given a matrix like this:

```
m = matrix(c(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
             c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
             c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
             c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),
             c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),
             c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0),
             c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0),
             c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)), ncol = 10, byrow = T)
```

I could potentially in some way apply something like one dimensional `split` function. For example: for row [1]

> 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0

`split(row[1])` = `[1 1 1], [1 1]` because I take zeros as cut and trim value. So in my example with array I'd expect 3 smaller matrices to get:
M 1

```
a = matrix(c(c(0,1,0,0,0),
             c(1,0,1,1,1),
             c(1,0,0,0,1),
             c(0,1,0,0,1),
             c(0,1,1,1,1),
             c(0,1,1,1,0)), ncol = 5, byrow = T)
```

M 2

```
b = matrix(c(c(1,1,1),
             c(0,0,1)), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
```

M 3

```
c = matrix(c(c(1),
             c(1),
             c(1),
             c(1)), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
```

if I'm not mistaken. Is it some simple way to achieve it? I now code in R (but maybe Python). Basically, I can use it for 1D but in 2D it's becoming tricky because rows depend on columns. Btw, I need to save coordinates of the original placement.

**EDIT**
I've edited the input to be reproducible. I've got a hit it's raster solution: How to keep coordinates or original matrix?
That means, the row and column ids for each new matrix from the original matrix.

Comment: How do you decide how many pieces you get?

Comment: The same way as `split` decides. For example for string: `str_split("ax aax   ax  ax ", "\\s+")` gives `["ax", "aax", "ax, "ax"]`

Comment: as a formatting tip, next time instead of pasting your matrices with ">" do it without them and in between the ` symbol

Comment: Questions not focused on a single language are generally regarded as too broad.

Comment: @Peter.k: That doesn’t mean anything in more than one dimension, where there isn’t a sequence that alternates between 0 and non-zero.

Comment: @boski Sorry, editing on this website is really horrible. I'll put reproducible code instead.

Comment: Your edit suggests that it’s the connected components that you’re after, but then one could be inside another, or overlapping in a way that chained several together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand, but here's a raster solution. First, I create the matrix.

```r
# Create matrix
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text  = "0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"))
```

Then, I load the `raster` library and convert my matrix to a raster.

```r
# Load raster library
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

# Convert to raster
ras <- raster(mat)
```

Here, I find the clumps of cells that are ones.

```r
# Create clumps including diagonals
clu <- clump(ras, directions = 8)
#> Loading required namespace: igraph
```

This function pulls out each clump.

```r
# Extract & trim clumps, then turn NAs to zeros
clumpy <- function(x){
  tmp <- as.matrix(trim(match(clu, x)))
  tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
  tmp
}
```

And here I apply the function to all clumps.

```r
lapply(unique(clu), clumpy)
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    0    0    1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#> [2,]    1    0    1    1    1
#> [3,]    1    0    0    0    1
#> [4,]    0    1    0    0    1
#> [5,]    0    1    1    1    1
#> [6,]    0    1    1    1    0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1]
#> [1,]    1
#> [2,]    1
#> [3,]    1
#> [4,]    1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

Here's a version of `clumpy` that retains row and column numbers.

```r
# Extract & trim clumps, then turn NAs to zeros
clumpy <- function(x){
  # Find clump
  foo <- as.matrix(match(clu, x))
  # Rename columns & rows
  colnames(foo) <- 1:ncol(foo)
  rownames(foo) <- 1:nrow(foo)
  # Trim
  tmp <- as.matrix(trim(foo))
  # Replace NAs with zeros
  tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
  # Return matrix
  tmp
}

# [[1]]
#   6 7 8
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 0 0 1
# 
# [[2]]
#   2 3 4 5 6
# 2 0 1 0 0 0
# 3 1 0 1 1 1
# 4 1 0 0 0 1
# 5 0 1 0 0 1
# 6 0 1 1 1 1
# 7 0 1 1 1 0
# 
# [[3]]
#   8
# 4 1
# 5 1
# 6 1
# 7 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm talking about. Could you assure this is optimal algorithm and for large matrices it's worth to be used? And how to keep the original coordinates?

Comment: @Peter.k No, I can't say this is an optimal solution, just that it's a solution.

Comment: @Peter.k I've updated my answer in order to retain column and row numbers.

Comment: Yes. Now it's great, many thanks! Saved my day. I've already found `chunks = t(matrix(clu@data@values, ncol = 8, byrow = F))` gives a coordinates by group.